# "No query Unable to fetch row" in Qt app

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, qsqlquery

I am creating a table using `sqlite` database in Qt 5.9 and I am getting this error:

> No query Unable to fetch row

```
QSqlQuery query("create table credit(username text primary key, password text);");
if(!query.exec())
{
    ui->result->append("dataentry unsuccessful...\n"+query.lastError().text()+"\n");
}
else
{
    ui->result->append("looks good...");
}
```

Comment: ...looks like a missing comma after `username text` in the `create` query?

Comment: @chowlett no thats valid syntax

Comment: more likely is that query runs queries not ddl statements. The error says 'i see no query here'. Most wrapper have an execute-non-query method too

Comment: @pm100 - that might be true for SQL in general, but it looks like sqlite requires the commas - see the structure diagram at the top of https://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html

Comment: here is an example of qt create table http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtsql-cachedtable-example.html

Comment: ...which uses `QSqlQuery::exec`, and the `create table` has commas everywhere. I'm not saying it definitely _is_ the comma, but it'd be worth a go.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. DDL statements are possible within QSqlQuery. But there is no need to add the semi-colon(;) at the end of `"create table credit(username text primary key, password text);"`
2. Secondly, when you create a QSqlQuery object with query string as parameter, it executes it immediately. There is no need to call `query.exec()`.

You can substitute the `exec()` with a `isValid()` method to check validity of the query in the condition.

Hope this helps.